# How to Rename drive letter title or description via batch file

Tags: rename, drive, letter

How can I rename drive letter/description through batch file?

e.g.
right now it says "Blah (\Server) (W:)"
I can right click on it and choose rename to "Newname (W:)"

I would like to do this through a batch file, please help!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/625243/change-a-drive-letter-from-command-prompt-or-batch-script-in-windows-8

Comment: @enigma   the post that you cited seems to be about changing the letter assigned to a drive,  not renaming it.  I think that the OP needs to know about `label`    Please type `label /?` at a command prompt to get the syntax.

Comment: @G5W I tried to type label W:Newname but didn't work, it gave me: Cannot change label on this volume. The request is not supported.

Comment: @JCprog   I just changed the name of a thumb drive on my machine just like what you typed. Just to confirm,  are you on a windows machine?

Comment: @JCprog  You are right.  This worked fine from the command line,  but did not work in a batch file.

Comment: @G5W it seems to me that it can't be done easily with a command line but I found this [link](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/ezine/ezine60.htm) and it does what I was looking for.